# data-enhance="false" not applying when i refresh a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2.
Some where in my code i don't want to apply jquery mobile css.So i used this script

### script

```
 $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

Its working fine when i first time open a page.But when i refresh a page its taking jquery mobile css.
Here is the link to jsffidle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5kt98yn/)

Click on "Slide to Page Two".And refresh only that frame,Then it  takes jquery mobile css.How to stop taking jquery mobile css even though i refresh a page.

Comment: I actually see applied styles on both pages... Maybe you should apply these settings in `head` write after scripts are included.

Comment: In my page i have added that script after a jquery mobile css and script.But its not working.

Comment: Are you using _single_ (each page in a separate file) or _multi-page_ model (all pages in one file)?

Comment: I have placed two template files (which contains first page and second page) and included in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override jQuery Mobile's defults (global settings), you should wrap your code in `mobileinit` and place it after jQuery.js and before jQuery Mobile.js in `head`.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.extend($.mobile, {
          ignoreContentEnabled: true,
          ajaxEnabled: false,
          loadingMessage: false
      });
  });
</script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4vze992L/show)**